# How to find the process id with the help of the sql transaction id in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, transactions

Below are the two transactions(1054674323,1054543833) working on one table. The transaction(1054543833) is locking the table more than 2 hours and not allowing for other queries on same table.

```
lock_id                         lock_trx_id     lock_mode       lock_type       
1054674323:65023:2362:49        1054674323      X       RECORD  
1054543833:65023:2362:49        1054543833      X       RECORD
```

Could you please tell me how to find the process ID of the 1054543833 transaction?

Comment: Perhaps you have `autocommit=0` and forgot to close with `COMMIT`?

Answer (score 0):

Use: That give you all informations about LOCKS and Querys.

```
    SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
    SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

Answer (score 0):

information_schema.innodb_trx contains both

- trx_id: transaction id
- trx_mysql_thread_id: process id

So you can get the mapping relationship from it.